# main.scala does not appear in IntelliJ 14

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, functional-programming, intellij-14

I am using IntelliJ 14 to learn Scala. When trying to launch a new project I expect in the src folder to find a main.scala file.

Unfortunately it is not the case. Is it something that I should create myself? Or am I missing an IntelliJ setting?

I have downloaded the Scala IntelliJ plugin, I had previously installed SBT and Play.

Comment: Even for learning the programming language, I'd suggest you use a build tool, such as **Maven** (which is probably the most common in the Java world), **SBT** (which is the standard Scala build tool), or ... Having a proper build can save you a lot of frustration. Regarding your question: Having a proper set-up, you can (in IntelliJ) right-click on a source-folder and click **new** -> **Package** or **new** -> **Scala Class**. Default Windows shortcut: `<alt>+<insert>`. The entry point must be in a  Scala `object` with the signature `def main(args: Array[String]): Unit`

Comment: Thanks, SBT is supposed to be included in the Scala - intelliJ plugin, so I guess I am good with this. I do see it on intelliJ when I click new projects.

Comment: Regarding the New Package / New Scala Class Procedures, I do them but I do not get this "entry point" from scratch,which was the case in NetBeans. I can ofc copy/paste but I was just wondering if I had done something wrong during the setup or if everything is normal like this.

Comment: So you're looking for a project template? In Maven, you can use Archetypes (http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html), but you'd still have to look for an archetype that fits your needs. I don't know if archetypes can also be used to create SBT projects. However, if you just want to use the same project setup for multiple projects, you could simply setup the project once, then commit the setup to your version control system (or simply copy the files somewhere else) and re-use it. Maybe someone else knows a better solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `main.scala` is not a convention in Scala.

If you just want to execute some code, you can use scala worksheet in intellij (or better, the built-in scala REPL).

Comment: OK, I think this answers my question. I thought I had to find this main.scala and main Object somewhere in a new project. Apparently not.